# How to get zoom level in time series data as callback input in Dash

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, plotly-dash, dashboard

Given a line graph with time series data in Dash (Plotly) dashboard, when I zoom in and the resolution of the x-axis (timestamp) change, how can I capture that as an input to another callback?

What I want to achieve, is plot-B displaying data based on the zoom in plot-A. When plot-A zooms in, plot-B automatically follows.

Note that plot-A and plot-B are using different dataset, with matching timestamps.

Answer (score 10):

Sample code for synchronizing the zoom level in plotly dash.

```
app=dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([
                dcc.Graph(id='graph',figure=fig),
                html.Pre(id='relayout-data', style=styles['pre']),
                dcc.Graph(id='graph2', figure=fig)])

@app.callback(Output('relayout-data', 'children'),
              [Input('graph', 'relayoutData')])
def display_relayout_data(relayoutData):
    return json.dumps(relayoutData, indent=2)


@app.callback(Output('graph2', 'figure'),
             [Input('graph', 'relayoutData')], # this triggers the event
             [State('graph2', 'figure')])
def graph_event(select_data,  fig):
    try:
       fig['layout'] = {'xaxis':{'range':[select_data['xaxis.range[0]'],select_data['xaxis.range[1]']]}}
    except KeyError:
       fig['layout'] = {'xaxis':{'range':[zoomed out value]}}
return fig

app.run_server()
```

Comment: Your solution unfortunately overwrites the complete layout of the figure in the callback function. I have written an improved answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/64891612/179014 .

Answer (score 4):

Here is an improved version of the callback based on the the answer from @Sachin Dev Sharma:

```
@app.callback([Output('graph2', 'figure')],
         [Input('graph', 'relayoutData')], # this triggers the event
         [State('graph2', 'figure')])
def zoom_event(relayout_data, *figures):
    outputs = []
    for fig in figures:
        try:
            fig['layout']["xaxis"]["range"] = [relayout_data['xaxis.range[0]'], relayout_data['xaxis.range[1]']]
            fig['layout']["xaxis"]["autorange"] = False
        except (KeyError, TypeError):
            fig['layout']["xaxis"]["autorange"] = True

        outputs.append(fig)

    return outputs
```

The advantage here is, that we don't overwrite the complete layout of the figure in the callback. We only overwrite the `xaxis.range` and `xaxis.autorange` property. Also this solution allows to set the zoom on multiple output figures by accepting multiple figure arguments (see `*figures`).

Comment: Your solution is more complete, but I don't quite understand the `*figures` trick. Isn't it always referring to graph2 figure State? For multiple figures, I use different approach, see my answer bellow.

Answer (score 0):

The Dash docs have an answer for this [here](https://dash.plot.ly/dash-core-components/graph).

> relayoutData
>
> Data from latest relayout event which occurs when the user zooms or pans on the plot or other layout-level edits. Has the form {: } describing the changes made. Read-only.

Unfortunately, as a read-only prop, you will not be able to update the second graph to follow the zoom on the first one.

Comment: Thanks, it's helpful to know relayoutData. I do think there are several ways to take that read-only data, and use it to update the other graph. Either through data, or axis properties of the graph?

Comment: If there is, it is not something I am familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

Posting little bit different solution for multiple figures than @asmaier proposed

```
for p in ['graph1', 'graph2', 'add-your-graphs']:
    @callback(
        Output(p, 'figure'),
        [
            Input('graph', 'relayoutData'),
            State(p, 'figure')
        ]
    )
    def update_zoom(relayout_data, figure, component=p):
        if relayout_data is None:
            raise PreventUpdate

        try:
            figure['layout']["xaxis"]["range"] = [relayout_data['xaxis.range[0]'], relayout_data['xaxis.range[1]']]
            figure['layout']["xaxis"]["autorange"] = False
        except KeyError:
            raise PreventUpdate
        return figure
```